# How to get the coverage in SonarQube from Maven Multiproject using PowerMock and Jacoco Offline Instrumentation

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, powermock, jacoco

I am having a Maven multiproject build. I am using Powermock to mock the Classes for writing Unit test cases. So, inorder to get the jacoco coverage, I am using Jacoco offline instrumentation, and setting sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports to get the Sonar Coverage. When I try doing that, I am getting errors thrown from Jacoco and Sonar:

```
[INFO] Analysing C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\target\jacoco.exec
[WARNING] Exception during analysis of file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\target\classes\cache\TestClass.class
java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\target\classes\cache\TestClass.class
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:155)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:130)
    at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:147)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.analyzeClassFile(JacocoReportReader.java:139)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.analyzeFiles(JacocoReportReader.java:114)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.readExecutionData(AbstractAnalyzer.java:133)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.analyse(AbstractAnalyzer.java:102)
    at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoSensor.execute(JaCoCoSensor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:286)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:279)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:259)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:cache\TestClass is already instrumented.
    at org.jacoco.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.assertNotInstrumented(InstrSupport.java:176)
```

I am not sure why jacoco is trying to instrument the class again to get the Sonar Coverage. I am stuck with this problem for a while. Any help would be great.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the SonarJava version, found in Administration -> Marketplace in versions 6.7+ and in Administration -> System -> Update Center in 6.6 and below.

Comment: Example of using PowerMock with JaCoCo Offline Instrumentation and Maven in our repository: https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/tree/master/jacoco-offline. Then you can import of coverage to SonarQube using any appropriate way.

Comment: @VaL I can get the data file created by Jacoco. The problem is that in Jenkins when I try running sonar as part of CI, it throws the error. I am not sure why sonar is trying to instrument the classes again.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam The SonarJava version is : 4.14.0.11784

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/instrument-mojo.html :

> Performs offline instrumentation. **Note that after execution of test you must restore original classes with help of ["restore-instrumented-classes" goal](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/restore-instrumented-classes-mojo.html).**

Exception message `already instrumented` is misleading, but exactly this message is produced on attempt to analyze instrumented classes instead of original ones.

Comment: <execution><id>default-instrument</id><goals><goal>instrument</goal></goals></execution><execution><id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id><goals><goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal></goals></execution>. I have added "restore-instrumented-classes" as well. I see the issue when sonar is trying to analyze the data file.

Comment: Analysing \target\jacoco.exec
[WARNING] Exception during analysis of file \cache\TestClass.class. And the error is caused as it is trying to instrument the TestClass again. I see it is analyzing the jacoco.exec and then analyzing the target class and tries instrumenting it.

Comment: @FarheeAslam as a JaCoCo and SonarQube developer I can assure you that instrumentation is never performed during analysis. Once again - error message and stack trace clearly indicate that you try to analyze instrumented class, whereas must analyze original and that's it. Wild guess - maybe you simply forgot to do `clean` after addition of `restore-instrumented-classes` ?

Comment: The instruction that I execute in Jenkins are 1) mvn clean install -DskipTests 2) mvn clean test 3) mvn -Psonar org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=TestProject. Could you  please tell which of the steps in wrong in this ? @Godin

Comment: the problem for me is when I am executing the third command "mvn -Psonar org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=TestProject"

Comment: @FarheeAslam as per already mentioned documentation ( http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/restore-instrumented-classes-mojo.html ) `restore-instrumented-classes` binds by default to `prepare-package`, which comes after `test` - see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html Therefore not executed when you do `mvn clean test` and pretty sure that logs shows that it is not executed. It will be executed for example in case of `mvn clean verify`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on in your case, but I have managed to generate PowerMock coverage with Jacoco, using `powermock-module-javaagent`.

Just make sure you put powermock agent **after** jacoco agent:

```
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <argLine>${jacocoArgLine} -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/powermock/powermock-module-javaagent/${powermock.version}/powermock-module-javaagent-${powermock.version}.jar -noverify</argLine>
...
```

If you want to see an example, take a look at this project: https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner

Here you can see that sonar takes into account static methods and `new` statements mocked by PowerMock:

[image]

If you want to mock `new`statements make sure you use `PowerMockRule` instead of `PowerMockRunner`.

Take a look at [this test](https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner/blob/master/src/test/java/es/jfcorugedo/CalculatorConstructorTest.java)